# Keep keyboard open on mobile when touch outside input

Tags: javascript

I have a few photos and when a user touch each photo, i show a different `input` field to edit text.

You tap the first `input`, keyboard is opened and you edit it.
Now if a user wants to show  the **next** `input` **while keyboard is open**, he touches the next photo, but keyboard will closed.

How to keep keybaord open and let user touch photos and focus on next `input` ?

Tried this without success :

```
  document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("hidden");
  document.getElementById(id).focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single `input` element for all the images.

Just store the values of `input`s in an array which is initially set to a blank string. Then based on the image selected, set the value of `input` to the corresponding value from the array.

```
// No. of images
let n = 5; // Take 5 for example
let values= []; // will contain values like { imageId: string, value: string }

// Initialize the values here
    ...
// End of initialization

// Current selected image is
let selectedImage = 'someId'; 

// Let all the images have a class `.image`
let images = document.querySelectorAll('.image');
for(let i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    images[i].onclick = function () {
          let textBox = document.querySelector('#input');
          // Store the value in the array before
          values = values.map(function(m) {
                if (m.imageId === selectedImage) {
                    return {
                        imageId: m.imageId,
                        value: textBox.value
                    };
                }
                return m;
          });
          textBox.value = values.filter(function(m) {
             return m.imageId === this.id;
          })[0].value;
    };
}
```

Comment: this is not working. once you touch a new photo keyboard is closed.